# Create dialog in umbraco 6.0.5 is empty

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I am working on an Umbraco(6.0.5) project and eveything was fine till yesterday. Today, the Create dialog stopped working properly on the main Content tree and the Media tree. The dialog is just coming up empty as shown in the attached image. This is affecting all the existing subfolders too.

I opened the chrome developer tools to see if there are any JS errors but didn't find any. The CMS is making a call to the backend to get the fields that should populate the Create dialog and the call has a 200 OK status but an empty response.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things like this don't just happen, and in a CMS like Umbraco it is unlikely that it has just broken :)

However, there are a few things to check:

Look at the internal Umbraco logs `~/app_data/logs/` as thee will show you where it is falling over. There may be a timeout, a file it can't find and the logs will record all exceptions and warning etc.

Depending on where the CMS is hosted, check the Event Viewer for application issues.

If you don't have ELMAH installed in the application, install it. It's one of the first things I install. I set it to ignore 404 errors but log and email me regarding any other exceptions.

Finally, it's vital that you review what happened between yesterday and today. Check the source control logs, check whether any new files have been deployed, check whether any amendments have been made to data types, document types or directly to the database. Like I say, things like this don't just happen. It is much more likely that a change has been made that has knocked something out. If you don't check, this could and most likely will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this - took me several hours, but here is what I came up with.

First - try to update the compilation value in your web.config to debug="true". Clear cache and etc. When you tried this, does the create dialog work for you? When I tried this, it worked for me - which led me to notice it was an issue with Client Dependency in the back office.

If this still sounds like we were having the same issues - here is how I resolved it. Client Dependency framework has a setting for rogue file compression (you'll find it at the bottom of ClientDependency.config).

Basically - that dialog is creating an iframe to an aspx file - and what I want to do is not compress the files on that iframe. Here is the setting I used to do this.

```
<rogueFileCompression>
 <add path="*" compressJs="true" compressCss="true" jsExt=".js,asmx/js" cssExt=".css">
    <exclusions>
    <add path="^.*create.aspx.*" />
    </exclusions>
  </add>
</rogueFileCompression>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 4.9.1 and I struggled to find any real answers. What fixed it for me in the end was to shutdown IIS, then delete all of the files in the following locations:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Then after starting IIS again it worked perfectly